# Sending CSV file via WebClient : No serializer found for class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, webclient, multipartfile

## I'm trying to Send a Multipart File using WebClient :

```
    public Mono<UploadReportDto> uploadOffers(MultipartFile file) {
            return this.offerWebClient.getOfferWebClient(WebClient.builder()).post()
                            .uri("/upload")
                            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData("file", file))
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(UploadReportDto.class);
    }
```

## The Response I get :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-07-24T09:32:12.441+00:00",
    "status": 500, 
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile[\"inputStream\"])
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.